# How to write to excel sheet only those rows which match the condition using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jira

I have a data frame which contains 3 columns(Issue id, Creator, Versions).I need to extract the row which does not contain the value "<JIRA Version" in the "versions" column(Which is the third and fifth row in my case.Similarly there could be multiple rows in the data frame)

Below is the code i'm trying, but this is actually printing all the rows from the data frame. Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

```
allissues = []
for i in issues:
    d = {
    'Issue id': i.id,
    'creator' : i.fields.creator,
    'resolution': i.fields.resolution,
    'status.name': i.fields.status.name,
    'versions': i.fields.versions,

            }
allissues.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(allissues, columns=['Issue id', 'creator', 'versions'])
matchers = ['<JIRA Version']

for ind in df.values:
     if matchers not in df.values:
         print(df['versions'][ind], df['Issue id'][ind])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

some minor changes in your code:

```
allissues = []
for i in issues:
    d = {
    'Issue id': i.id,
    'creator' : i.fields.creator,
    'resolution': i.fields.resolution,
    'status.name': i.fields.status.name,
    'versions': i.fields.versions,

            }
allissues.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame(allissues, columns=['Issue id', 'creator', 'versions'])
matchers = '<JIRA Version'

for ind,row in df.iterrows():
     if matchers not in row.versions:
         print(row['versions'], row['Issue id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Yash. But i'm getting the below error:

 File "jirapanda.py", line 36, in <module>
    if matchers not in row.versions:
  File "C:\Users\\Miniconda3\envs\jiraccess\lib\site-packages\jira\resources.py", line 823, in __eq__
    return self.id == other.id and self.name == other.name
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'


Also, in this  condition ( if matchers not in row.versions:) , versions is the column name. would this condition work in this case?

Comment: No luck Yash. Still getting the same error. As an alternate option, i wrote a JQL(JIRA query) to fetch only those rows which have versions column value as empty. Thanks for your help.